# gl_bitmap texture mode behavior doesn't follow spec?

Tags: opengl

For reasons detailed
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716855/opengl-opencl-interop-transfer-times-texturing-from-bitmap)
I need to texture a quad using a bitmap (as in, 1 bit per pixel, not an 8-bit pixmap).

Right now I have a bitmap stored in an on-device buffer, and am mounting it like so:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, BFR.G[(T+1)%2]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, W, H, 0, GL_COLOR_INDEX, GL_BITMAP, 0);
```

The OpenGL spec has this to say about glTexImage2D:
*"If type is GL_BITMAP, the data is considered as a string of unsigned bytes (and format must be GL_COLOR_INDEX). Each data byte is treated as eight 1-bit elements..."*

Judging by the spec, each bit in my buffer should correspond to a single pixel. **However, the following experiments show that, for whatever reason, it doesn't work as advertised:**

1) When I build my texture, I write to the buffer in 32-bit chunks. From the wording of the spec, it is reasonable to assume that writing 0x00000001 for each value would result in a texture with 1-px-wide vertical bars with 31-wide spaces between them. However, it appears blank.

2) Next, I write with 0x000000FF. By my apparently flawed understanding of the bitmap mode, I would expect that this should produce 8-wide bars with 24-wide spaces between them. Instead, it produces a white 1-px-wide bar.

3) 0x55555555 = 1010101010101010101010101010101, therefore writing this value ought to create 1-wide vertical stripes with 1 pixel spacing. However, it creates a solid gray color.

4) Using my original 8-bit pixmap in GL_BITMAP mode produces the correct animation.

**I have reached the conclusion** that, even in GL_BITMAP mode, the texturer is still interpreting 8-bits as 1 element, despite what the spec seems to suggest. The fact that I can generate a gray color (while I was expecting that I was working in two-tone), as well as the fact that my original 8-bit pixmap generates the correct picture, support this conclusion.

**Questions:**

1) Am I missing some kind of prerequisite call (perhaps for setting a stride length or pack alignment or something) that will signal to the texturer to treat each byte as 8-elements, as it suggests in the spec?

2) Or does it simply not work  because modern hardware does not support it? (I have read that GL_BITMAP mode was deprecated in 3.3, I am however forcing a 3.0 context.)

3) Am I better off unpacking the bitmap into a pixmap using a shader? This is a far more roundabout solution than I was hoping for but I suppose there is no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: I doubt hardware supports it, and the fact that the current spec deprecates it likely means that support in the driver will be patchy at best. I'd suggest working around it using a format that has current support.

Comment: Based on what I've seen from further experiments, I think this is a fair assessment. It really does appear that modern hardware no longer supports 1-bit-per-pixel. I'm going to implement a shader to convert my packed bitmap into a supported format. Thank you for your suggestion.